# How to check if a value is in an array in a table

Tags: postgresql, array, postgresql-11

I have a table if key - array pairs and need to check if a string is an element in a given array in this table. I have managed to write an if statement to check if the element is in an array but if I try to get the array from the table it does not work.

In the example below,
`SELECT list FROM public."HelloWorldTable" WHERE name = 'HelloWorldList'`
selects the list element that contains an array that is identical to the one in the other if statement but I can not seem to access it the same.

**MWE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "HelloWorldTable"(
    Name text PRIMARY KEY,
    List text[]
);

INSERT INTO public."HelloWorldTable" (name, list) VALUES ('HelloWorldList', ARRAY['Hello', 'World']);

DO $$
BEGIN 
  IF 'Hello' = ANY (ARRAY['Hello', 'World']::text[]) THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Found';
  ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'Not found';
  END IF;

-- failing attempt:

--  IF 'Hello' = ANY (SELECT list FROM public."HelloWorldTable"
--    WHERE name = 'HelloWorldList') THEN
--      RAISE NOTICE 'Found';
--  ELSE
--      RAISE NOTICE 'Not found';
--  END IF;

END $$;
```

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array) but I can not get it working the way I need it to. I have tried adding `::text` and `::text[]` to the second if statement but I only get different errors.
How can I solve this?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) *Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements*

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for a simple `select * from helloworldtable where 'Hello' = any (list)`?

Comment: If you really need to store key/value pairs, a `jsonb` column would be a much better choice (provided the de-normalization makes sense to begin with)

Comment: Note: I removed the redundant `UNIQUE` constraint, orthogonal to the problem. (And PK columns are `NOT NULL` automatically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead:

```
DO $do$
BEGIN 
   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM hello_world_table
      WHERE  name = 'HelloWorldList'
      AND    'Hello' = ANY (list)
      ) THEN 
       RAISE NOTICE 'Found';
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE 'Not found';
   END IF;
END $do$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=23ef553c2b1324dfc0fdf5b10d440d17)*

With a subselect between the parentheses, like you tried, the `ANY` construct expects a ***set*** of element types, not an array. That would work with the column `list` being type `text`, not `text[]`.

I can see how this is confusing, as Postgres *automatically* extracts the single value from a single column in a returned set in most other contexts to match the expected form. Like:

```
SELECT '{Hello,World}' = (SELECT list FROM hello_world_table WHERE name = 'HelloWorldList');
```

The untyped string literal `'{Hello,World}'` is even cast to `text[]` automatically, deriving the type from the subselect on the other side.

**But** in this case, the `ANY` construct is resolved to its alternative form *expecting* a set, which makes your attempt fail.

You ***could*** make it work by unnesting the array to produce the expected *set*:

```
SELECT 'Hello' = ANY (SELECT unnest(list) FROM hello_world_table
                      WHERE name = 'HelloWorldList');
```

But don't. Use an `EXISTS` subquery instead and move the condition to the `WHERE` clause like demonstrated.

Related:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860)
- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231965/939860)
- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11892796/939860)